# Pass Arguments other than event & ID to @selector iOS

Tags: ios, dynamic, arguments, selector

I am creating an iOS app as defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22706812/time-based-ios-auto-start)! So here in this app I am using a segmented control (Dynamically added) to give the user the choice to select one of the options. When the user selects a choice I want to send a string to selector method, so I wanted to know if we can send anything apart from id and event to an action:@selector that we add.

Here's the code

```
NSArray *optionsArray =[NSArray arrayWithArray:qna2.answers];
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:optionsArray];
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(xOffset,yOffset, 250, 50);
[segmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:UISegmentedControlNoSegment];
[self.view addSubview:segmentedControl];
yOffset+=100;

[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(MyAction:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

So can we do like @selector(Myaction: Category) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to store the string in a property like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *myString;
```

Then, retrieve the value in the `myAction:` method.

Or you could subclass your control and add a property that way:

```
@interface MySegmentedControl : UISegmentedControl

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *stringProperty;

@end
```

When you set each segmented control:

```
MySegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[MySegmentedControl alloc] initWith...];
segmentedControl.stringProperty = @"Some meaningful value";
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

In the change handler:

```
- (void) myAction:(MySegmentedControl *)sender
{
    NSString *importantString = sender.stringProperty;
    // do stuff with importantString
}
```

Comment: I will be adding 10s of questions each belonging to a specific category, so when a particular segmentedcontrol is touched, I want that method to know which category does that question belong to?... In this scenario How would I do it?

Comment: Thanks to @Zev, I could resolve the issue by adding a property accessibilityHint to the segmentedcontrol.

Comment: I meant store the value in a property in your class, not in the segmented control. It’s bad practice to overload existing properties like that - what if you need to use `accessibilityHint` later for its intended purpose?

Comment: There are many segmented controls being shown on the screen, I would appreciate if you could explain with an example how would a class property help me in determining which segmented control was activated?.. I have to remind you that I am new to iOS and objective-c ...

Comment: Oops, changed the `myString` property from `strong` to `copy`, which is best practice for properties of types that have mutable subclasses (like `NSString` and `NSMutableString`), in case the string you passed in later gets mutated. I also added an example of the subclassing code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this makes sense, i have tried this and it works.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to subclass `UISegmentedControl`, say `MYUISegementedControl`, and create a delegate protocol so that it can call back to your `UIViewController`.

When you create your `MYUISegmentedControl` instance you can add whatever additional properties you need and pass this information back to the delegate, or at the very least your delegate can access these properties off the `MYUISegmentedControl` properties.

You could also use a category rather than a subclass.